# how can I debug a meteor tutorial in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-debugging

I am a total newbie to app development (I have minimal coding experience with Mathematica, Fortran, C, etc, I'm a retired physicist). I tried to do the meteor tutorial:https://react-tutorial.meteor.com/simple-todos/01-creating-app.html, but in order for me to understand what is going on, I need to step through the js and jsx files in a debugger. I couldn't figure out how to do this in VSC. Can someone help?

Comment: maybe that is not what I need. I need someone to just help me get up to speed so I can do some development. I'd be willing to pay